# Get location name from Latitude & Longitude in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cllocationmanager, reverse-geocoding

I want to find current location name from latitude and longitude,

Here is my code snippet I tried but my log shows null value in all the places except in `placemark`, `placemark.ISOcountryCode` and `placemark.country`

I want value of `placemark.locality` and `placemark.subLocality` but it is showing null values.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // this creates the CCLocationManager that will find your current location
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

// this delegate is called when the app successfully finds your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;

                       }

                       NSLog(@"placemarks=%@",[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]);
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                       NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode =%@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.country =%@",placemark.country);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.postalCode =%@",placemark.postalCode);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.administrativeArea =%@",placemark.administrativeArea);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.locality =%@",placemark.locality);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.subLocality =%@",placemark.subLocality);
                       NSLog(@"placemark.subThoroughfare =%@",placemark.subThoroughfare);

                   }];
}

// this delegate method is called if an error occurs in locating your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);
}
```

**Thanks In Advance.**

***EDIT:***

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil)
        NSLog(@"longitude = %.8f\nlatitude = %.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);

    // stop updating location in order to save battery power
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];


    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
         if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

             // strAdd -> take bydefault value nil
             NSString *strAdd = nil;

             if ([placemark.subThoroughfare length] != 0)
                 strAdd = placemark.subThoroughfare;

             if ([placemark.thoroughfare length] != 0)
             {
                 // strAdd -> store value of current location
                 if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                     strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark thoroughfare]];
                 else
                 {
                     // strAdd -> store only this value,which is not null
                     strAdd = placemark.thoroughfare;
                 }
             }

             if ([placemark.postalCode length] != 0)
             {
                 if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                     strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark postalCode]];
                 else
                     strAdd = placemark.postalCode;
             }

             if ([placemark.locality length] != 0)
             {
                 if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                     strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark locality]];
                 else
                     strAdd = placemark.locality;
             }

             if ([placemark.administrativeArea length] != 0)
             {
                 if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                     strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark administrativeArea]];
                 else
                     strAdd = placemark.administrativeArea;
             }

             if ([placemark.country length] != 0)
             {
                 if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                     strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark country]];
                 else
                     strAdd = placemark.country;
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: You need to use some 3rd party API like `Google Places API`.

Comment: No need to use Google's paid service - this functionality is built right into iOS. Look at CLLocation and CLPlacemark. It will provide you any level of granularity you want from coords, eg. country, city, region, timezone, etc etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm giving you snippet which I'm using for resolving address. I'm including comment also at neccessary place to understand the code for you. Besides that feel free to ask any question from snippet if you get fail to understand anything.

Write following snippet in `didUpdateToLocation` method

```
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil)
    NSLog(@"longitude = %.8f\nlatitude = %.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);

// stop updating location in order to save battery power
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];


// Reverse Geocoding
NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");

// “reverseGeocodeLocation” method to translate the locate data into a human-readable address.

// The reason for using "completionHandler" ----
   //  Instead of using delegate to provide feedback, the CLGeocoder uses “block” to deal with the response. By using block, you do not need to write a separate method. Just provide the code inline to execute after the geocoding call completes.

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
    {
        placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

        // strAdd -> take bydefault value nil
        NSString *strAdd = nil;

        if ([placemark.subThoroughfare length] != 0)
            strAdd = placemark.subThoroughfare;

        if ([placemark.thoroughfare length] != 0)
        {
            // strAdd -> store value of current location
            if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark thoroughfare]];
            else
            {
            // strAdd -> store only this value,which is not null
                strAdd = placemark.thoroughfare;
            }
        }

        if ([placemark.postalCode length] != 0)
        {
            if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark postalCode]];
            else
                strAdd = placemark.postalCode;
        }

        if ([placemark.locality length] != 0)
        {
            if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark locality]];
            else
                strAdd = placemark.locality;
        }

        if ([placemark.administrativeArea length] != 0)
        {
            if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark administrativeArea]];
            else
                strAdd = placemark.administrativeArea;
        }

        if ([placemark.country length] != 0)
        {
            if ([strAdd length] != 0)
                strAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",strAdd,[placemark country]];
            else
                strAdd = placemark.country;
        }
```

Where strAdd will return address using geolocation..

Enjoy Programming !!

Comment: `currentLocation` is unknown

Comment: currentLocation is newLocation from this method.. check my updated answer

Comment: hey I have done all for you. You just need to replace your code in - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation with mine, and you will have your answer.

Comment: I am getting error like `placemarks.subThoroughfare` not found in NSAraay.

Comment: did you integrate corelocation.framework, because this variable resides in that framework only

Comment: make sure you have written #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> in your header file from where you are accessing this method

Comment: ok, post your code what you have written in didUpdateToLocation method

Comment: initialize  CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init]; in viewDidLoad only.

Comment: Doesn't matter i have problem in this lines, I am getting error like `placemark.subThoroughfare` not found in NSAraay

Comment: Please clean up the code & build again, it should not return any error

Comment: apple demo sample is also showing null value, why it is any idea ? `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097`

Comment: where is subthroughfare in this sample example?

Comment: I'm not able to find this line in sample example

Comment: you misunderstood,dude not in sample example, i am getting error in your code snippet.. i just gave u another example of apple which is also not showing city name..

Comment: are you getting the value of thoroughfare? i.e. placemark.thoroughfare??

Answer (score 11):

**Method with completion block:**

```
typedef void(^addressCompletion)(NSString *);

-(void)getAddressFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location complationBlock:(addressCompletion)completionBlock
{
    __block CLPlacemark* placemark;
    __block NSString *address = nil;

    CLGeocoder* geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
         {
             placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
             address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@", placemark.name, placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality];
             completionBlock(address);
         }
     }];
}
```

**This is how to use it:**

```
CLLocation* eventLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:_latitude longitude:_longitude];

[self getAddressFromLocation:eventLocation complationBlock:^(NSString * address) {
        if(address) {
            _address = address;
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 8):

I implemented Niru's solution in **Swift 3**, posting here should anybody need it:

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.location!) { (placemarksArray, error) in

    if (placemarksArray?.count)! > 0 {

        let placemark = placemarksArray?.first
        let number = placemark!.subThoroughfare
        let bairro = placemark!.subLocality
        let street = placemark!.thoroughfare

        self.addressLabel.text = "\(street!), \(number!) - \(bairro!)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use google api for reverse geotagging :

URL : 
   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false

From : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: it's not free API.

Answer (score 0):

If the location you are trying to get is listed in this list then there is something wrong in your code..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2289/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011305

otherwise CLGeoCoder doesnt have addresses to other countries.

I faced the same problem so i used this to get the address.. Gives a really accurate address.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false

Answer (score 0):

First of all, filter locations in didUpdateToLocation to prevent use cached or wrong locations for geocoding

```
NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

if (abs(locationAge) > 5.0) return;

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;
```

Also, try to move the reverseGeoCoding method away from didUpdateToLocation

Comment: apple demo sample is also showing null value, why it is any idea ? `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `latitude`, `longitude` values of a location you can use [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder)
here is a [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_clgeocoder/) which might help you.

Comment: And it can be used for iOS 5 and above versions

Comment: apple demo sample is also showing null value, why it is any idea ? `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097`

Comment: apple demo sample is also showing null value, why it is any idea ? `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097`

Comment: Are you trying this in a simulator? If yes try this on a device.

Answer (score 0):

use this API for getting the data and pass lat and long values.

[API for Geo location](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=true)

Comment: apple demo sample is also showing null value, why it is any idea ? `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        //..NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            lblgetaddrees.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",
                                  placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                  placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                  placemark.administrativeArea,
                                  placemark.country];
        } else {
            //..NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1, this is one of my solution. Here i'm using **geocode** API to get the complete address. With this api i can get the village names also.

I'm using **reverseGeocodeLocation** but it's not getting village address details or village names, it's getting only near by city names.
It's one of the finest solution....

```
func getAddressForLatLng(latitude: String, longitude: String)  { // Call this function

     let url = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(latitude),\(longitude)")//Here pass your latitude, longitude
     print(url!)
     let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)

     if data != nil {
        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
        print(json)

        let status = json["status"] as! String
        if status == "OK" {

            if let result = json["results"] as? NSArray   {

                if result.count > 0 {
                    if let addresss:NSDictionary = result[0] as? NSDictionary {
                        if let address = addresss["address_components"] as? NSArray {
                            var newaddress = ""
                            var number = ""
                            var street = ""
                            var city = ""
                            var state = ""
                            var zip = ""
                            var country = ""

                            if(address.count > 1) {
                                number =  (address.object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary)["short_name"] as! String
                            }
                            if(address.count > 2) {
                                street = (address.object(at: 1) as! NSDictionary)["short_name"] as! String
                            }
                            if(address.count > 3) {
                                city = (address.object(at: 2) as! NSDictionary)["short_name"] as! String
                            }
                            if(address.count > 4) {
                                state = (address.object(at: 4) as! NSDictionary)["short_name"] as! String
                            }
                            if(address.count > 6) {
                                zip =  (address.object(at: 6) as! NSDictionary)["short_name"] as! String
                            }
                            newaddress = "\(number) \(street), \(city), \(state) \(zip)"
                            print(newaddress)

                            // OR 
                            //This is second type to fetch pincode, country, state like this type of data

                            for i in 0..<address.count {
                                print(((address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["types"] as! Array)[0])
                                if ((address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["types"] as! Array)[0] == "postal_code" {
                                    zip =  (address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["short_name"] as! String
                                }
                                if ((address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["types"] as! Array)[0] == "country" {
                                    country =  (address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["long_name"] as! String
                                }
                                if ((address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["types"] as! Array)[0] == "administrative_area_level_1" {
                                    state =  (address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["long_name"] as! String
                                }
                                if ((address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["types"] as! Array)[0] == "administrative_area_level_2" {
                                    district =  (address.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary)["long_name"] as! String
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Call this function like this

```
self.getAddressForLatLng(latitude: "\(self.lat!)", longitude: "\(self.lng!)")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
import CoreLocation

func printAddress() {
  if let lat = Double(30.710489), lat != 0.0, let long = Double(76.852386), long != 0.0 {
  // Create Location
  let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
  // Geocode Location
  CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
           // Process Response
           self.processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
         }
     }
}

private func processResponse(withPlacemarks placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) {
       var address = ""
        if let error = error {
            address = "Unable to Reverse Geocode Location (\(error))"
        } else {
            if let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first {
                address = placemark.compactAddress ?? ""
            } else {
                address = "No address found"
            }
        }
        print(address)
    }
extension CLPlacemark {
var compactAddress: String? {
    if let name = name {
        var result = name

        if let street = thoroughfare {
            result += ", \(street)"
        }
        if let city = locality {
            result += ", \(city)"
        }
        if let postalCode = postalCode {
            result += ", \(postalCode)"
        }
        if let country = country {
            result += ", \(country)"
        }
        return result
    }

    return nil
}
}
// 2nd Way

func updateLocation(lat:Double,long:Double) {
           CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: Double(lat), longitude: Double(long)), completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
               if error != nil {
                   return
               }
               else {
                  var location = ""
                   let pm = placemarks![0]
                   if pm.addressDictionary!["FormattedAddressLines"] != nil    {
                       location =  "\n" + (pm.addressDictionary!["FormattedAddressLines"] as! NSArray).componentsJoined(by: ", ")
                   }else{
                       location = "\n" + "NO_ADDRESS_FOUND"
                   }

               }
               })
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the address from Location Coordinate (lat,long).

You can get the address info such like city, country, postcode etc. from LocationCoordinates with this code

```swift
func getReverSerGeoLocation(location : CLLocation) {
    print("getting Address from Location cordinate")

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {
        placemarks , error in
    
        if error == nil && placemarks!.count > 0 {
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.last else {
                return
            }
            print(placemark.thoroughfare)
            print(placemark.subThoroughfare)
            print("postalCode :-",placemark.postalCode)
            print("City :-",placemark.locality)
            print("subLocality :-",placemark.subLocality)
            print("subAdministrativeArea :-",placemark.subAdministrativeArea)
            print("Country :-",placemark.country)
        }
    }
}
```

Just call above method by passing latitude longitude as argument such like below

```swift
    getReverSerGeoLocation(location: CLLocation(latitude: 21.0225, longitude: 72.5714))
```

Hope this helps!