# How can I get google maps location name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I am working on an application in which I need to print the location after clicking on Google Map. I have retrieve the coordinates where the user tap on the map, Now I need to retrieve the name of the country. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at following topics:

1) [Get location name from Latitude & Longitude in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647996/get-location-name-from-latitude-longitude-in-ios)

2) [How to retrieve user's current city name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrieve-users-current-city-name)

Quite a lot of code so I don't see any sense to copy-paste the answers. Hope, this will be helpful

**UPD.:** Here are the links to Google API reference:

A common tutorial: [Hello Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

iOS SDK docs: [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/?csw=1)

Comment: is there a way to do it without using geocoding ? or any tutorial about geocoding ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with links to google maps API. It's quite easy to use. Or You just need to choose necessary API call and parse it properly. Possible API call is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=20.714224,-74.961452