# Not able to get subLocality using CLPlacemark in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, clplacemark

I'm actually building an application in swift.
The problem is that the application should get the sublocality from a longitude latitude and check if that subLocality is part of an array but I'm not able to get the sublocality

Can any of the professional here help me out

This is the longitude Latitude used

```
let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:43.60089111328125, longitude: 3.875329601741884)

ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in
                        if (error != nil)
                        {
                            print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                        let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

                        if pm.count > 0 {
                            let pm = placemarks![0]
                            addressString = ""

                            if pm.name != nil {
                                addressString += pm.name! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.isoCountryCode != nil {
                                addressString += pm.isoCountryCode! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.country != nil {
                                addressString += pm.country! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.postalCode != nil {
                                addressString += pm.postalCode! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.administrativeArea != nil {
                                addressString += pm.administrativeArea! + ", "
                            }
                            if pm.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                                addressString += pm.subAdministrativeArea! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.locality != nil {
                                addressString += pm.locality! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.subLocality != nil {
                                addressString += pm.subLocality! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                                addressString += pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
                            }

                            if pm.subThoroughfare != nil {
                                addressString += pm.subThoroughfare! + ", "
                            }
                            if pm.areasOfInterest != nil {
                                print(pm.areasOfInterest!)
                            }

     print(pm.addressDictionary)
}
})
```

Which should return GAMBETTA as subLocality but nothing is coming.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647996/get-location-name-from-latitude-longitude-in-ios/51797299#51797299

Comment: "Nothing is coming" because you are not _asking_ for sublocality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Geocoder` for reverse geocoding based on the location coordinates which will return a `CLPlacemark`  and then you can check for the `subLocality` if exists like the following:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
    // Place details
    guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }

    // SubLocality
    if let subLocality = placeMark.subLocality {
      // Do something if exists
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try, it will help you.

```
   let newlocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:43.60089111328125, longitude: 3.875329601741884)


        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newlocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            // Place details
            var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
            placeMark = placemarks?[0]

            print(placeMark.subLocality as Any)

            // Address dictionary
            print(placeMark.addressDictionary as Any)

            //City
            if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["City"] as? String {
                print("city : \(city)")
            }

     })
```