# how to get city name via CLlocationManager using latitude and longitude in IOS?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, city

I am trying to get address via CLLocationManager using latitude and longitude but it only returns state and country name, I want city also, I am attaching my code can anybody tell me that how can I alter my code to get city name also.Below is my code

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder1 = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

     NSLog(@"Detected Location : %f, %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    //CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:26.9260 longitude:75.8235];

    CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    [geocoder1 reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                       if (error) {
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;
                       }

                       if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
                       {
                           CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                           NSDictionary *addressDictionary =
                           placemark.addressDictionary;

                           NSLog(@"%@ ", addressDictionary);
                           NSString *address = [addressDictionary
                                                objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                           NSString *city = [addressDictionary
                                             objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
                           NSString *state = [addressDictionary
                                              objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
                           NSString *zip = [addressDictionary
                                            objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];


                           NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", address,city, state, zip);
                       }

                   }];
}
```

Comment: You're not really getting "address via CLLocationManager".  You're getting it via CLGeocoder (CLLocationManager is just giving you coordinates).  Code looks ok.  It may be specific to the coordinates which CLGeocoder (Apple) may not be able to geocode well (Google seems to be better at this).  Are the coordinates 26.9260, 75.8235?

Answer (score 7):

Try this ..

```
-(NSString*)getAddressFromLatLong : (NSString *)latLng {
    //  NSString *string = [[Address.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"+%@",cityTxt.text] stringByAppendingFormat:@"+%@",addressText];
    NSString *esc_addr =  [latLng stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[result dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSMutableArray *dataArray = (NSMutableArray *)[data valueForKey:@"results" ];
        if (dataArray.count == 0) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter a valid address" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }else{
            for (id firstTime in dataArray) {
                NSString *jsonStr1 = [firstTime valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];
                return jsonStr1;
            }
        }

    return nil;
}
```

Send comma separated Latitude longitude .. and try It's working fine

Reference Link [**Get Address From Latitude Longitude using Apple Function in iOS & iPad**](http://www.jogendra.com/2013/07/get-latitude-longitude-from-address.html)

Comment: i do'nt want to use google map API , is there any way to get city name using CLLocationManager.

Comment: In last project I used this .,, But I don't about CLLocationManager... Please try to search , if available by this then sure you will get ... Try to search more ,.,..

Answer (score 0):

You are using k-constants from ABPerson class from AddressBook framework for CLGeocoder object keys. While some may match, I'm pretty sure others will not.

You can try ...

```
NSMutableArray *addrArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//to return address line(s)
addrArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [p.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]];
[addrArray removeLastObject]; //country name
NSString *addressString = [addrArray componentsJoinedByString:@" ,"];
#if DEBUG
                NSLog(@"Address: %@", addressString);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

We will get Complete **Address** based on latitude and longitude.Here is the Sample Code.

```
 - (void) getAddressFromLatLon:(CLLocation *)location
 {

      CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
      [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error){
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [array objectAtIndex:0];
     NSLog(@"City %@",placemark.subAdministrativeArea);
     NSLog(@"State %@",placemark.administrativeArea);

     }];
 }
```

In below i mentioned different types.So easily you can check it.These are all belongs to **CLPlacemark** class objects.This class can be available on [**CoreLocation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/) Framework.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *name; // eg. Apple Inc.
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *thoroughfare; // street name, eg. Infinite Loop
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *subThoroughfare; // eg. 1
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *locality; // city, eg. Cupertino
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *subLocality // neighborhood, common name, eg. Mission District
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *administrativeArea; // state, eg. CA
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *subAdministrativeArea; // City, eg. Santa Clara
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *postalCode; // zip code, eg. 95014
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *ISOcountryCode; // eg. US
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *country; // eg. United States
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *inlandWater; // eg. Lake Tahoe
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *ocean; // eg. Pacific Ocean
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSArray<NSString *> *areasOfInterest;
```

What ever you want you just add it and get the result.Here is reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515639/iphone-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longtiude/21741468#21741468) .