# how can find city name from latitude longitude in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get City via CLLocationManager using latitude and longitude.
City name get some time and not get sometime so how can i solve this issue.

```
-(Void)ViewDidload
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation  fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    CLLocation *location =newLocation;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    NSString *urlcvs=[[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?     latlng=%@,%@&sensor=false",latitude,longitude]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *urlss=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlcvs];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlss];
    NSData *res=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *mainstr=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:res encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dic=[mainstr JSONValue];
    NSString *tempstr=[[[dic valueForKey:@"results"]valueForKey:@"formatted_address"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array1=[tempstr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    Citynamestr=[array1 objectAtIndex:array1.count-3];
    NSLog(@"location is : %@",app.Citynamestr);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide test lat,long? (Where you are not getting city's name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Get City name from Latitude and Longtiude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515639/iphone-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longtiude)