# MKReverseGeocoder "deprecated in iOS 5"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mkreversegeocoder

It say it is "deprecated in iOS 5".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location // You can pass aLocation here instead
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() , ^ {
                           // do stuff with placemarks on the main thread

                           CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                           NSString *zipString = [place.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"ZIP"];

                           [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showWeatherFor:) withObject:zipString];



                       }
            }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what the question is - can you be a little more clear about what exactly you're asking?

Comment: When when i type MKReverseGeocoder in xcode it says that it is "deprecated in iOS 5". does that help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MKReverseGeocoder` is deprecated in all firmwares after iOS4. This just means that it is now obsolete and frowned upon to be using the outdated class. Use `CLGeocoder` instead, like so:

```
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location // You can pass aLocation here instead 
                       completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
                               // do stuff with placemarks on the main thread

                           if (placemarks.count == 1) {

                           CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


                           NSString *zipString = [place.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"ZIP"];

                           [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showWeatherFor:) withObject:zipString];

                           }

     });

}];
```

If you want to reverse geocode a hardcoded pair of coordinates perse --

Initialize a CLLocation location with your latitude and longitude:

```
    CLLocation *aLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
```

I also want to point out that you can still use `MKReverseGeocoder`. It may be removed with future iOS updates though.

Comment: Thanks for sharing i seem to be getting errors? do i put inside the if statement?

Comment: Well how are you using it? What errors are you getting? It depends on the context. The code above simply reverse geocodes the current location of the user. I've edited my answer so that you can reverse geocode a **specific** location.

Comment: Ok because now my app is not showing its current location. Also where would i implant your code into my code?

Comment: It depends. Can you provide some context? And what errors are you getting?

Comment: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showWeatherFor:) withObject:@"95301"]; this is all that works. but does not give current location only the zip code entered in the code. i want my app to find your location. the errors are expected ). no @end.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to get the user's current location? Can you try rewording? And what do you mean the errors are expected.

Comment: Oh that's easy. Ok so to get the zip code from the array of placemarks, use `valueForKey`. I'll add it in my answer

Comment: OK so im confused why your code is giving me errors can you give what you put in the .h? like what is "place"?

Comment: What errors are you getting? I can't tell you what to do if I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: ok my errors. undeclared identifier place. the curley brackets are what seems to be giving me errors.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot one line. Look back at the answer.

Comment: Yes, `CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: What do I declare "place" as?

Comment: I just added it, it is of type `CLPlacemark`.

Comment: Ok down to 2 errors "expected ]" and "expected }"

Comment: I understand I just don't understand the errors. I  have never had this issue before. I think tge issue might have to do with the "dispatch_sync" am I correct?

Comment: Where are you getting your errors? Post how you've used my answer in your code.

Comment: Ok I posted my updated code above. sorry i took so long. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot to close a `)` and a `]`

Comment: Add a conditional to make sure that the array placemarks actually contains anything. Take a look at the edit

Comment: Do i need     CLLocation *aLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude]; and what did you declare longitude as? Thanks!

Comment: That's only if your reverse geocoding some other location. You don't need that if you are just using the current location. Add the conditional in the updated answer. Everything should be working fine.

Comment: Ok getting closer! i got an issue that says. "local declaration of 'place' hides instance variable"

Comment: The app Doest seem to be finding the current location.

Comment: That's probably because you have an instance variable called `place` in your header file which coincides with the place variable used for reverse geocoding. So you can just change the name of the `CLPlacemark` variable to like aPlace and then make sure to change it in the zipString assignment

Comment: why is my phone not asking me for my current location?

Comment: What do you mean? The answer I've provided should work fine provided you've implemented the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Just curious, why did you unaccept my answer? It should work fine.

Comment: When i run it my phone is not asking me to use my current location. so i am wondering where i went wrong if my phone isn't even looking for its location?

Comment: Am is supposed to use this CLLocationManager?

Comment: Well how did you get the current location of the phone before? You need the coordinates of your current iPhone location so that you can pass it as a `CLLocation` variable when reverse geocoding.

Comment: Ok that what i need help with. If you could help me that would be AWESOME!

Comment: Is This it?   - (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    [geocoder release];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showWeatherFor:) withObject:[placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"ZIP"]];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{    
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:%@ didFailWithError:%@", geocoder, error);
    
    [geocoder release];
}

Comment: What do you mean **is that it**? Is that it for what? No, that will not get you the iPhone's current location. Here's a tutorial on getting the iPhone's current location using CoreLocation: http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/

Comment: i mean is this the code? i know core location just dont know how to intergrade it.

Comment: Ok i will let you know what i get.

Comment: Will the code you gave me work with this http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/29/adding-local-weather-conditions-to-your-app-part-22-accessing-googles-xml-weather-api/ that I showed you earlier?

Comment: well thats all i am trying to do and its still not working.

Comment: implanted the tutorial and its still not working can you help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your tacit question, but the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says to use [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder) instead.

Comment: So do I just replace MKReverseGeocoder with CLGeocoder? and do i add a delegate?

Comment: No, but the answer to this question describes how to update your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809142/clgeocoder-and-backward-compatibility