# MKReverseGeocoder deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios6, mapkit, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

I just saw that MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated. Question is, how do you change to CLGeocoder the easiest way? Sorry for the extremely long source code (i think you think it's pretty simple, but im new to this). This is what I got before...

StoreLocation.h

```
@interface StoreLocation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *subtitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;

- (NSString *)subtitle;

- (NSString *)title;

@end
```

StoreLocation.m

```
@implementation StoreLocation
@synthesize coordinate,subtitle;

-(NSString *)subtitle{

    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([userDef boolForKey:@"SavedAddress"]) {
        NSString *savedAddress = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SavedAddress"];
        return savedAddress;
    }
    else {
        return subtitle;
    }
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coor{
    self.coordinate=coor;
    return self;
}


- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coor {
    MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coor];
    geocoder.delegate = self;
    coordinate = coor;
    [geocoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"fail %@", error);
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    self.subtitle = [placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Street"];

    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDef setValue:subtitle forKey:@"SavedAddress"];
}
```

MapViewController.m

```
    -(void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation{

    MKGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
        [geocoder start];
    }


    - (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark{
        NSString *streetAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                                   [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey],
                                   [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey]];

        mapView.userLocation.subtitle = streetAddress;      
    }
-(IBAction)storeLocation {

    StoreLocation *position=[[StoreLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];    [mapView addAnnotation:position]; }


    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview
                viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)dropPin
    {
        if ([dropPin isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class])
        {
            return nil;
        }

        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annot"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:dropPin reuseIdentifier:@"annot"];
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        }
        else {
            pinView.annotation = dropPin;
        }
        return pinView;
    }
```

Thanks a thousand times!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this?

MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated in all firmwares after iOS4. This just means that it is now obsolete and frowned upon to be using the outdated class. Use CLGeocoder instead, like so:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locationManager.location // You can pass aLocation here instead 
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
                           // do stuff with placemarks on the main thread

                       if (placemarks.count == 1) {

                       CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


                       NSString *zipString = [place.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"ZIP"];

                       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showWeatherFor:) withObject:zipString];

                       }

 });
```

}];
If you want to reverse geocode a hardcoded pair of coordinates perse --

Initialize a CLLocation location with your latitude and longitude:

```
CLLocation *aLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
```

I also want to point out that you can still use MKReverseGeocoder. It may be removed with future iOS updates though.

Comment: Copy pasting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832150/mkreversegeocoder-deprecated-in-ios-5